# hbase rowkey filter on multiple values

Tags: hadoop, nosql, hbase, couchbase-view, hbase-filter

I have created an Hbase table rowkey with combination of multiple column values.
my data of rowkey in hbase look like below.
'123456~raja~ram~45000~mgr~20170116'
'123456~raghu~rajan~65000~mgr~20150106'

i am trying to filter condition just like in sql
as 
select * from table
where deptid =123456 and name='rajan'

how can i do (or) and (and) conditions.
i am using below code to filter the condition

scan 'tablename', {FILTER => (org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.RowFilter.new(CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'),SubstringComparator.new("123456"))) && (org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.RowFilter.new(CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'),SubstringComparator.new("rajan")))}

if i use same code with swapping values i am getting different results

scan 'tablename', {FILTER => (org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.RowFilter.new(CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'),SubstringComparator.new("rajan"))) && (org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.RowFilter.new(CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'),SubstringComparator.new("123456")))}